# How to replace all characters in a user input string except one

Tags: java, character, replace

I'm currently in an introductory level Java class, and am working on the classic phrase guess assignment. The object is for one user to enter a secret phrase, and another to guess it one letter at a time. Between guesses, the phrase must be displayed as all question marks except the letters that were guessed correctly. Our class has only really covered some very basic methods, if-else statements and loops up to this point, but I'm trying to research some string methods that may make this a bit easier.

I know of the `replace()`, `replaceAll()` and `contains()` methods, but was wondering if there is a method which allows you to replace all but one character of your choice in a string.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use [`String.replaceAll()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
String out = str.replaceAll("[^a]", "?");
```

This will leave all letters `a` intact and will replace all other characters with question marks.

This can be easily extended to multiple characters, like so:

```
String out = str.replaceAll("[^aeo]", "?");
```

This will keep all letters `a`, `e` and `o` and will replace everything else.

Comment: Awesome,thanks so much, that makes perfect sense. Now, can I reference another string (say, a string that stores a user's guess at a character the string may contain) in that regex that excludes characters? Or does something like this require more of a transitive approach?

Comment: @user1019310: You can build the regex on the fly: `"[^" + chars + "]"`, where `chars` is the string containing the chars you want to exclude.

Comment: ^^^ Perfect, that is absolutely what I need. Thanks a lot for the help everyone. I'll post up if I run into any more walls.

Comment: One more, how do I exclude whitespace characters from the characters replaced?

Comment: @user1019310: Just add them to the regex like any other character, e.g. `"[^ aeo]"`