# Replace string char exception

Tags: java

I have a piece of code which replaces all of a string with dashes. How do I make it so that if the word contains a space, it will not dash that space but rather leave it as a space.

Code:

```
public String hiddenWord(){
     word = randomWord.getRandomWord();
     String dashes = word.replaceAll(".", " _ ");
     return dashes;
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the requirement. Can you share an example input and the output you'd like to get for it?

Comment: Basically, the random word is converted into all dashes. The problem is, I want an exception for a space. Right now, even a space is dashed.

Comment: Usually a word is the characters between spaces. Can you give an example of a word with a space in it?

Comment: For example, hard disk. Instead of 8 dashes it gives 9. I would like a space between the two words.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#predef

Comment: Please [search thoroughly](/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+replace+all+but+one+character) before posting. More on searching [here](/help/searching).

Answer (score 2):

> I want an exception for a space. Right now, even a space is dashed.

Try

```
dashes = word.replaceAll("[^ ]", " _ "); // everything but space
```

or

```
dashes = word.replaceAll("\\S", " _ "); // non white space
```

Comment: Thank, this worked!

Comment: FYI, duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940053/how-to-replace-all-characters-in-a-user-input-string-except-one

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I suggest you close, though in this case non white space is perhaps a better answer.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I can't, I mis-closed it once. (It's no biggie either way.)